# QGIS - Using polyline layer as cookie cutter on polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to create a new polygon layer of neighborhood blocks:

- I have a simple polygon of the outline of a city
- I have a road layer (polyline)
- I want to use the road layer to 'cut' into the city outline, to give me an output that has the areas within the roads be made into individual 'blocks'.

I'm familiar with how to do this in ArcGIS or MapInfo but not QGIS... any pointers?

The Difference function only appears to work if both layers are polygon.

I found 'Clipper' plugin and 'Clip Multiple Layers' Plugin but couldn't appear to get them to work.

I have verified that my two layers have the same coordinate system

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use
[Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgissplitwithlines):

This algorithm splits the lines or polygons in one layer using the lines in another layer to define the breaking points. Intersection between geometries in both layers are considered as split points